# How to click on the button that is there in a content dialog for a UWP app using coded UI?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

am testing an UWP app with coded UI. I have a content dialog box with two buttons Yes & NO.

Coded UI fails to find the control for Yes & No buttons.

In the test builder when I highlight the parent for the content dialog box is shown as the Main Window, not the content window.

That is the way to develop UWP apps.

To reproduce the similar problem, please follow the steps:

1) Open movies app

2) Click on the add button

3) Try to click on the add button

Coded UI throws an exception "Playback failed to identify the control"

Please help on how to resolve the issue, where in the parent is still been shown as main window.

Comment: When you use Coded UI's cross-hairs (i.e. assertion) tool, can you get a blue border drawn around the YES button or the NO button? Or, is the smallest area with a blue border drawn around the parent controls?

Comment: Yes I do so the blue border on the parent control , but not on the buttons.

Comment: To clarify. You do not get a blue border around the YES button. You do not get a blue border around the YES button. You do get blue border around the parent control. In that case it is likely that the parent control is a custom control that does not support Coded UI. Ask its developers what level of support it has for either MSAA or UIA that Coded UI uses. If they say none then also ask them whether their control is usable by people with vision difficulties that mean they need to use screen readers. (Does you application need to be usable by screen readers?)

Comment: @AdrianHHH: The issue is  I have a custom content dialog box in my UWP app, as the default content dialog box is allowed only 2 buttons and we have to display more that 2 buttons. So if the button are there in the text area of content dialog coded UI fails click on the button. No my app is not meant to be used by people with vision difficulties.

Comment: A custom control that does no support MSAA or UIA cannot be controlled by Coded UI. You need to get the developers of that control to add support for the MSAA or UIA interfaces that Coded UI needs to access the control.